# Slow for loop with inconsistent timing

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop

I have a for loop that is approximately this:

```
Timer timer1, timer2;
double inner_loop_time = 0;
timer1.Reset()
for (int i = 0; i < num_steps; i++) {
  timer2.Reset();
  sample_point += delta;

  // Find some points close to the sample_point.
  std::vector<int> point;
  FindClosestPoints(sample_point, &new_keypoints);
  // Insert the keypoints into a global container.
  candidate_keypoints.insert(new_keypoints.begin(),
                             new_keypoints.end());
  inner_loop_time += timer2.ElapsedTimeInSeconds();
}
const double outer_loop_time = timer1.ElapsedTimeInSeconds();
std::cout << "Inner loop time: " << inner_loop_time 
          << " vs outer loop time: " << outer_loop_timer;
```

When I run this code, I get dramatic inconsistencies in the between the timing in the inner loop and outer loop. E.g. the outer loop reports 0.96s and the inner loop reports 0.51s. Why are these timings inconsistent?

Other notes:

- The Timer class is a wrapper for c++11 time library. It is efficient and not the reason for the difference in timings.
- The function FindClosestPoints is self-contained and does not spawn any threads.
- This weird timing behavior is consistent across thousands of runs.
- num_steps is on the order of 1000

Comment: What makes you think the c++11 time library is efficient, getting the time from a machine is not a fast process. Try running a loop only getting the time and see if that accounts for your difference.

Answer (score 0):

`inner_loop_time` does not include the time to destroy `std::vector<int> point` or the time spent inside `timer2.Reset()`.

Comment: Objects are destroyed in the reverse order they're created, so it should include the time to destroy `point`.

Comment: Objects within a scope are destroyed in the reverse order they are created when the scope exits. `timer2.ElapsedTimeInSeconds()` is called before the scope exits.

Comment: does `timer2.ElapsedTimeInSeconds` account for its own call time? There will be a little bit in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on `num_steps`. Every loop cycle does make a small difference between the two timers. Because you have a gap between reseting the inner timer and calculating the passed time.

The time difference should be proportional. You can calculate it with

```
diff = num_steps * gap_time
```